# "Segmentation Fault" error during JNI implementation

Tags: android, android-studio, java-native-interface

I am trying to call java method from C using JNI interface in android studio.

Here's my C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
 #include<jni.h>

 int main(int argc, char **argv)
 {

     //printf("Android Test Application.\n");
     //return 0;
     static JNIEnv* jniENV;
     int exiting;
     JavaVM* jvm;
     jint number=20;

     printf("1");
     int gotVM = (*jniENV)->GetJavaVM(jniENV,&jvm);
     //LOGI("Got JVM: %s", (gotVM ? "false" : "true") );
     jclass javaClass;
     jmethodID javaMethodId;

     //javaClass= (*jniENV)->FindClass(jniENV, "java/einfo/NDKSample/MainActivity");
     printf("2");
     javaClass= (*jniENV)->FindClass(jniENV, "MainActivity");
     printf("3");
     javaMethodId= (*jniENV)->GetStaticMethodID(jniENV, javaClass, "square", "(I)I");
     printf("4");

     printf("%d squared is %d\n", number,(*jniENV)->CallStaticIntMethod(jniENV, javaClass, javaMethodId,number));
     //(*jniENV)->CallStaticIntMethod(jniENV, javaClass, javaMethodId,number);
    return 0;
 }
```

When I tried to run this program using abd shell it gives me "Segmenation Fault" error.

I am new to JNI and C, please help me to find the root cause for the problem.

FYI, I am using android studio in Windows 7.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I hate null pointer exceptions... And obviously jniENV pointer is null

Comment: So GetJavaVm() is not giving anything? what do I need to do to make this work?

Comment: Obviously, as it names states, it's giving javavm not jniENV... Also it is a pointer to the function in jniENV pointer which is null then it's not giving anything but crash....  Also AFAIK you can't start jvm(dalvik)  on android in this way...

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll try to find a new way to call java method from C in android.

Comment: Look for "native activities"

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old thread, but this might still be useful for someone.

It looks like you want to create your own java invocator. In that case you have to use JNI_CreateJavaVM(..). The call (*jniENV)->GetJavaVM(...) is meant for situations where native code is called from java. In the last case the native function passes a jniENV parameter.

For more information see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html#JNI_CreateJavaVM